# Create an A/B Sample Size Calculator using Evan Miller's Post

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, python, computational-statistics

To learn more about A/B Testing sample sizes selection I am attempting to use Evan Miller's popular blog-post to recreate a sample size calculator (https://www.evanmiller.org/sequential-ab-testing.html). However, there seems to be an error that prevents me from recreating the sample sizes given in article.  What would you suggest I re-examine to find a solution to my problem?

This error must be in my calculation or my reading of the problem.  Solving the constraint equations suggests a small sample size of ~6. The article suggests that the test statistic cutoff, which indicates if the treatment has a higher conversion rate than the control, is a function of the sample size.  Then it list two inequalities to solve for one variable, N the sample size.  How do I reproduce the sample size calculations?

Most of these problems would go away if the test statistic cutoff, d_star, wasn't a function of N.

d_star = z*Sqrt(N) // N is the sample size and z is the normal z-value

However, On the tables appearing the last half of the article d_star = z*Sqrt(N) relates N and d_star very precisely, which suggests d_star varies with N.

// Constraints given alpha and beta:
Sum R(p=1/(1+delta)) > 1 - beta
Sum R(p=1/2) < alpha

I'll append my Python 2.7 code and a plot for each constrain equation.

```
#### Begin Python Code to Calculate Sample Size ####
import random
import scipy.stats
import math
import sys
print sys.version

# Functions and helper functions to 
# calculate the sample size.
def calcStatPowerSum(N, script_delta):
    z = scipy.stats.norm.isf(alpha/2.0) #1.96 for alpha = 0.05
    d_star = z*(N**0.5)
    d_star = int(math.ceil(d_star))
    statPowerSum = 0
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        statPowerSum += (float(d_star)/i)*scipy.stats.binom.pmf((i+d_star)//2, i, 1.0-float(1)/(2+script_delta))
        # p and the (1-p) terms are reversed relative to the binomial distribution

    return statPowerSum

def calcCritValueSum(N, script_delta):
    z = scipy.stats.norm.isf(alpha/2.0) #1.96 for alpha = 0.05
    d_star = z*(N**0.5)
    d_star = int(math.ceil(d_star))
    critValueSum = 0
    for i in range(d_star, N+1, 2):
        critValueSum += (float(d_star)/i)*scipy.stats.binom.pmf((i+d_star)//2, i, 0.5)

    return critValueSum

def determineSampleSize(alpha, beta, script_delta):
    z = scipy.stats.norm.isf(alpha/2.0) #1.96 for alpha = 0.05
    d=1
    N=int(math.ceil(z*z))-1
    statPowerSum = 0
    critValueSum = 1
    while (statPowerSum <= 1 - beta or critValueSum >= alpha) and N<3000:
        d+=1
        N=int(math.floor(d*d/z/z))
        statPowerSum = calcStatPowerSum(N,  script_delta)
        critValueSum = calcCritValueSum(N, script_delta)

    return N


alpha = 0.05
beta = 0.8
lift = script_delta = 0.10
sampleSize = determineSampleSize(alpha, beta, script_delta)
print("beta:   ", beta, ", alpha:   ", alpha, ", sampleSize:   ", sampleSize)

##  The article suggests that N=2922 satisfies the constraint equations.
##  But the calculation suggests otherwise.
print("calcCritValueSum: ", calcCritValueSum(2922, script_delta))
print("statPowerSum:     ", calcStatPowerSum(2922, script_delta))

#### End Python Code ####
```

The following mathematica code reproduces the constraint plots as a function of d_star.  Copy and pasting the code into https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/  will generate these plots.  Generating more than one plot at a time will exceed the free usage limit.

```
(*   alpha constraint Plot   *)
z=1.96    (*alpha=0.05*)
Table[Sum[(d/n)*PDF[BinomialDistribution[Floor[d^2/z^2], 1/2], (d+n)/2], {n, d, Floor[d^2/z^2], 2}],{d,1,130}]
ListLinePlot[%, PlotRange->All, AxesLabel->{d_star,prob},PlotLabel->alpha Constraint Plot]


(*   1-beta constraint Plot   *)
delta=0.10
z=1.96    (*alpha=0.05*)
Table[Sum[(d/n)*PDF[BinomialDistribution[Floor[d^2/z^2], (1+delta)/(2+delta)], (d+n)/2], {n, d, Floor[d^2/z^2], 2}],{d,1,130}]
ListLinePlot[%, PlotRange->All, AxesLabel->{d_star,prob},PlotLabel->1- beta Constraint Plot]
```

Answer (score 6):

I took the logic from [this R function](https://gist.github.com/mottalrd/7ddfd45d14bc7433dec2) and rewrote it into the python function below, which gives the exact same output as Evan Miller's [Sample Size Calculator](https://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html). I'm not familiar with the approach you are taking in your specific implementation (nor Mathematica) but perhaps you can use this to troubleshoot your functions!

```py
def calc_sample_size(alpha, power, p, pct_mde):
    """ Based on https://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html

    Args:
        alpha (float): How often are you willing to accept a Type I error (false positive)?
        power (float): How often do you want to correctly detect a true positive (1-beta)?
        p (float): Base conversion rate
        pct_mde (float): Minimum detectable effect, relative to base conversion rate.

    """
    delta = p*pct_mde
    t_alpha2 = norm.ppf(1.0-alpha/2)
    t_beta = norm.ppf(power)

    sd1 = np.sqrt(2 * p * (1.0 - p))
    sd2 = np.sqrt(p * (1.0 - p) + (p + delta) * (1.0 - p - delta))

    return (t_alpha2 * sd1 + t_beta * sd2) * (t_alpha2 * sd1 + t_beta * sd2) / (delta * delta)
```

Comment: this is for relative delta. Is there a way for absolute delta and calculate number sample size? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Geoff's answer because I don't have enough reputation.

To answer Death Metal's question: to change the above to "absolute delta", all we need to do is set `delta = pct_mde` in the first line within the function. I modified Geoff's original function to work with **relative and absolute MDEs and for one and two-tailed tests**:

```
def calc_sample_size(alpha, power, p, pct_mde, delta_type='relative', num_tails="two"):
""" Based on https://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html and Geoff's (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/127726/geoff) Python implementation of the same.


Args:
    alpha (float): How often are you willing to accept a Type I error (false positive)?
    power (float): How often do you want to correctly detect a true positive (1-beta)?
    p (float): Base conversion rate
    pct_mde (float): Minimum detectable effect
    delta_type (str): either 'relative' or 'absolute'
    num_tails (str): either 'one' or 'two'

"""
delta = p * pct_mde
if delta_type == 'absolute':
    delta = pct_mde
    
t_alpha2 = scipy.stats.norm.ppf(1.0-alpha/2)
if num_tails == 'one':
    t_alpha2 = scipy.stats.norm.ppf(1.0-alpha)
t_beta = scipy.stats.norm.ppf(power)

sd1 = np.sqrt(2 * p * (1.0 - p))
sd2 = np.sqrt(p * (1.0 - p) + (p + delta) * (1.0 - p - delta))

return (t_alpha2 * sd1 + t_beta * sd2) * (t_alpha2 * sd1 + t_beta * sd2) / (delta * delta)
```

Calling the function with `calc_sample_size(0.05, 0.8, 0.2, 0.05, 'absolute', 'two')` gives us `~1030`, which the same result as Evan's calculator:

[image]